# Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 14 migration - frontend directory in the project missing post migration

Tags: vaadin8, vaadin14

I am working on a POC for Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 14 LTS migration for our project. After the application has migrated to 14, frontend directory under project directory is not found. Also I am not able to create a Vaadin Flow designer file because I get error as No Polymer is found in the project.

Should we create it manually under the project directory, or will it be created automatically after the maven build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should we create it manually under the project directory

Yes. Maven plugin does not generate it automatically as the folder is normally in our archetypes and project starter templates.